# Кнопка button не выполняет алгоритм

Tags: android, kotlin, button, textview, onclicklistener

Написал программу, которая выполняет следующий функционал: 1) заносятся данные в TextInputLayout; 2) при нажатии на Button эти данные считаются и выводятся в textview. Кнопка нажимается, но подсчёта не происходит.
Activity.kt файл:

```
class CalculatorActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_calculator)
        val mybth = findViewById<Button>(R.id.mybth)
        mybth.setOnClickListener{
            val editweight = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.urweighttext)
            val editheight = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.textInputLayout6)
            val editage = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.textinput1)
            val textView2 = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView2)
            val c: Double
            val S1: String = editweight.text.toString()
            val S2: String = editheight.text.toString()
            val S3: String = editage.text.toString()
            var a: Int = Integer.parseInt(S1)
            var b: Int = Integer.parseInt(S1)
            var d: Int = Integer.parseInt(S1)
            c = 10 * a + 6.25 * b + 5 * d
            textView2.text = c.toString()
        }
    }
}
```

XML файл:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/editage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".CalculatorActivity">


    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/toolbar2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/calculator"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/toolbar2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/toolbar2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/toolbar2" />

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/urweighttext"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="280dp"
        android:hint="@string/yourweight"
        app:boxStrokeColor="@color/gradient1"
        app:hintTextColor="@color/gradient1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar2"
        tools:ignore="InvalidId">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/editweight"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textInputLayout6"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="150dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="140dp"
        android:hint="@string/yoursize"
        app:boxStrokeColor="@color/gradient1"
        app:hintTextColor="@color/gradient1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar2">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/editheight"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textinput1"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="290dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
        android:hint="@string/urage"
        app:boxStrokeColor="@color/gradient1"
        app:hintTextColor="@color/gradient1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar2">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>



    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="124dp"
        android:text="@string/men"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar2" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="@string/women"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/checkBox" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:text="@string/pol"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/checkBox"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/urweighttext"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.789" />

    <TextView
        android:clickable = "true"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/calculate"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mybth"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.241"
        android:focusable="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/mybth"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/calculate"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/checkBox2"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.142" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У вас а б и ц переменные явно неправильно инициализированы

Comment: В чём заключается ошибка? Сейчас поменял val на var и в скобках заметил, что везде S1 стояло, теперь код выглядит так, но не работает:
```
var a: Int = Integer.parseInt(S1)
            var b: Int = Integer.parseInt(S2)
            var d: Int = Integer.parseInt(S3)
            var c: Double
```

Comment: `не работает` - это очень не информативно. Объясните подробнее. Выведите в логи значения всех переменных на всех этапах логики - наверняка заметите где и что не так.

Comment: Еще код можно попытаться отладить. Ставите точку останова в обработчике нажатия кнопки и все сразу станет понятно. https://developer.android.com/studio/debug

Comment: Сравните типы в разметке и в коде, тут у вас явные нестыковки. Пример `findViewById<EditText>(R.id.textinput1)`

Answer (score 1):

Ваша ошибка состоит в том, что вместо TextInputEditText, в которых содержится нужный вам текст, вы обращаетесь к обрамляющим их TextInputLayout, нужным для красивого движения подсказки в верхний левый угол поля.
Поэтому для того, чтобы приложение заработало, нужно во-первых дать имя третьему TextInputEditText, которое содержит возраст. То есть добавить id - editage :

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/textinput1"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="290dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
    android:hint="@string/urage"
    app:boxStrokeColor="@color/gradient1"
    app:hintTextColor="@color/gradient1"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar2">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/editage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

В классе MainActivity обратиться именно к TextInputEditText'ам:

```
val editweight = findViewById<TextInputEditText>(R.id.editweight)
val editheight = findViewById<TextInputEditText>(R.id.editheight)
val editage = findViewById<TextInputEditText>(R.id.editage)
```

Далее заменить S1 в двух местах на S2, S3 :

```
var a: Int = Integer.parseInt(S1)
var b: Int = Integer.parseInt(S2)
var d: Int = Integer.parseInt(S3)
```

Должно заработать, как мне кажется.